# cross validation function crossvalind

Tags: matlab, validation, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I have question please; concerning cross validation, for me the cross-validation is used to find the best parameters.
but I did not understand the role of this function "crossvalind":Generate cross-validation indices, it just takes a data set without model, like in this exemple :

```
load fisheriris
[g gn] = grp2idx(species);                     
[trainIdx testIdx] = crossvalind('HoldOut', species, 1/3);
```

Answer (score 1):

crossvalind() function splits your data in two groups: the training set and the cross-validation set.
By your example:
[trainIdx testIdx] = crossvalind('HoldOut', size(species,1), 1/3); means split the data in species (2/3 in the training set and 1/3 in the cross-validation set).
Supposing that your data is like:

species=[datarow1;datarow2;datarow3;datarow4;datarow5;datarow6] then 
trainIdx would be like [1;1;0;1;1;0] and testIdx would be like [0;0;1;0;0;1] meaning that from the 6 total elements in our set crossvalind function assigned 4 to the train set and 2 to the cross-validation set. Of course this is a random assignment meaning that the zero and ones indices will vary every time you call the function but the proportion between them will be fixed and trainIdx + testIdx will always be ones(size(species,1),1)

crossvalind('LeaveMout',size(species,1),2) would be exactly the same as crossvalind('HoldOut', size(species,1), 1/3) in this particular case. In the 'HoldOut' format you provide parameter P which takes values from 0 to 1 (like 1/3 in the example above) while with the option 'LeaveMout' you provide integer M like 2 samples from the 6 total or like 2000 samples from the 10000 total samples in your dataset. In case of 'Resubstitution': crossvalind('Resubstitution', size(species,1), [1/3,2/3]) would be yet the same but here you also have the option of let's say [1/3,3/4] meaning that some samples can be on both the train and cross-validation sets, or even [1,1] which means that all the samples are used in both sets (trainIdx=testIdx=[1;1;1;1;1;1] in the above example). I strongly suggest to type help crossvalind and take a look at the help file which is always a lot more detailed and helpful than i could ever be.

Comment: Thanks @CodeBlackj, it's clearer to me now, but please what is the difference between all this options :[Train, Test] = crossvalind('HoldOut', N, P)
[Train, Test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut', N, M)
[Train, Test] = crossvalind('Resubstitution', N, [P,Q])